# Stream Insight - Filter based on Type of Event

Tags: c#, streaminsight

So I am fairly new to Stream Insight and this might be a fairly basic question but it seems that filtering queries by event type is not supported (see below) so how should this be done?

To flesh out my question a bit, this is my CepStream...

```
var stockStream = CepStream<MarketDataPoint>.Create(appName, typeof(MarketdataPointInputAdapterFactory), new MarketDataAdapterConfig(), EventShape.Point);
```

.. and this is my query ...

```
var patternResult = from w in stockStream.Where(x => x is FxSpot)
                                            .AlterEventDuration(e => TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1))
                                            .SnapshotWindow(SnapshotWindowOutputPolicy.Clip)
                                        select new MarketDataPointEvent() {Price = w.Max(e => e.Price)};
```

...which yields this exception when run:
*The following expression is not supported by Microsoft Complex Event Processing LINQ Provider: (x is FxSpot)*

As I understand it, I could create multiple adapters than effectively perform the filter but this doesn't seem like the way it "should" be done.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Matt

Answer (score 1):

I would try to stay way from the is operator for type comparison. This is a sample using LINQPad, which I highly recommend to use. In this case the filter is done by stock. CTIs are automatically inserted by using

```
AdvanceTimeSettings.IncreasingStartTime
```

> Sample

```
void Main()     
{

    var marketReadings = new []
                    {
                    new MarketDataPoint() { Stock = "MSFT", Value = 30.0, Timestamp = DateTime.Parse("11/19/2012 4:10:00 PM") },
                    new MarketDataPoint() { Stock = "MSFT", Value = 30.1, Timestamp = DateTime.Parse("11/19/2012 4:11:00 PM") },
                    new MarketDataPoint() { Stock = "GOOG", Value = 667.97, Timestamp = DateTime.Parse("11/19/2012 4:12:00 PM") },
                    new MarketDataPoint() { Stock = "GOOG", Value = 667.51, Timestamp = DateTime.Parse("11/19/2012 4:12:00 PM") },
                };

            var stockStream = marketReadings.ToPointStream(Application, e=> PointEvent.CreateInsert(e.Timestamp,e),AdvanceTimeSettings.IncreasingStartTime);  

            var patternResult = from w in stockStream.Where(x => x.Stock == "MSFT")
                                                    .AlterEventDuration(e => TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1))
                                                    .SnapshotWindow(SnapshotWindowOutputPolicy.Clip)
                                                select new  {Price = w.Max(e => e.Value)}   ;

            patternResult.Dump();   
        }


        public class MarketDataPoint
        {
            public string Stock { get; set; }
            public double Value { get; set; }
            public DateTime Timestamp { get;set;}

        }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Donaciano but this doesn't really solve the problem. I am able to apply a filter on a property in the event as you have done. The problem that I have is with filtering by type. I know that I can set a property that corresponds to type in the event and filter by that but I was wondering if there was any way that it could be done using standard type comparison?

Answer (score 0):

The payload type you've defined is MarketDataPoint. This defines the schema for the event and according to [Event Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378905%28v=sql.111%29.aspx):
"Events in the StreamInsight server are an ordered list of fields instead of .NET structs, which do not impose an order on its fields."

A potential workaround for what you are trying to accomplish is to include all the needed fields in MarketDataPoint that comprise an FxSpot. Then add an additional property to MarketDataPoint to define what type of MarketDataPoint it is.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I should have mentioned in my question that MarketDataPoint is an abstract base class for FxSpot so it already has the necessary fields. Unfortunately, since the POCOs are being generated using Entity Framework, the discriminator is not available which I think is what you are suggesting. I guess that I'll just need to map from my POCO class to a new Event class that contains the discriminator in order to filter on that discriminator?

Comment: You can use FxSpot in your query, however, that must be the Payload type (i.e. CepStream<FxSpot>.Create()). Streams in StreamInsight can only contain 1 payload type. You can create multiple input adapters to bring in the different payloads or you may want to load everything into 1 payload type and after the CepStream<TPayload>.Create() step, filter and project into the actual payload type you want.